# Replacing values in a file using vi

Tags: bash, vi

I have a file which as multiple entries like "allowed_users 100", "allowed_hits 100", "allowed_users 10000".

Want to replace the values of "allowed_users 100" to "allowed_users 1000".

Best Wishes,
KJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:% s/allowed_users 100\>/&0/
```